# Rails - Making @projects avaialble on all page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On every page of my app I want to show a user's projects... So which controller do I use to make sure that @projects from the projects controller is being made available in the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your application_controller do the following:

```
before_filter :load_projects

def load_projects
  @projects = Project.all
end
```

That will run the load_projects method on every request and populate the @projects variable.

You can also add conditions to your before filter like so:

```
before_filter :load_projects, :only => [:index]

def load_projects
  @projects = Project.all
end
```

See more about ActionController filters:

- [Action Controller Filters - Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)
- [ActionController::Filters - API](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: if I have 2 before_filters. What's right.. Added two lines of before_filter or commas?

Comment: either, or... you need to be able to have multiple lines of before_filters so you can add conditions, etc. to them.  I'll add an example in the above answer.